# keep panel always bottom mdi application

Tags: delphi

I want to know, how to keep a panel always bottom of all mdi forms 
I have this..

```
      procedure TPanel.Loaded;
      begin
      Windows.SetParent(Handle, MainForm.ClientHandle);
      end;  


       procedure TPanel.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
         begin
           inherited;
           Message.WindowPos^.hwndInsertAfter := HWND_BOTTOM;
         end;
```

but, when I change the MDI form using system menu's form with command next, the panel its placed above
Thanks and sorry my english

Comment: I can't reproduce te described behavior (D2010). I've similar behavoir on Cascading which can be removed by adding *Procedure MyCascade(var msg:TMessage);message WM_MDICASCADE;* to then Mainform.

Comment: Apparently the system does not send a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message to non-MDIChild windows when the z-order of the children is changing. In newer versions of Delphi `ClientWndProc` is virtual, so you can override the handling in the main window, and, f.i. set the z-order of the panel after a `WM_MDIGETACTIVE` message.

Comment: @Manuel, are you deriving a new class from TPanel? I really don't get what's your problem. Feel free to reply and explain in Spanish and I'll translate it to English, and don't sorry for your's. :). Just don't forget to add my name with a @ (@jachguate) in your comment to make the system show a notification to me.